# php page prints null passing data through angularjs

Tags: php, angular, post, null, return

Good morning! I'm trying to pass an array from angularjs to php. I need to print the data on the php page and not return it to the function in angular js. On the php page it prints null but in the js function it receives the return correctly.

page html, listing data in table

```
<tr dir-paginate="rem in remessa | itemsPerPage:exibirQuant">
                    <td><a ng-click="buscarFunc(rem)" ng-bind="rem.nome"></a></td>
                    <!--<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="rem.selected" value="{{rem.nome}}" class="form-check-input"></td>-->
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{rem.nome}}" value="{{rem.nome}}" ng-model="rem.selected"></td>
                    <td>{{rem.valorBruto}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{rem.desconto}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{rem.valorLiquido}}</td>           
                </tr>

<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="salvar()">Salvar</button>
```

```
/* lists employees coming from the bank in a table */
$http.post('assets/php/remessa_rj.php', {'tipo':'listar', 'data_ini':$scope.data_start, 'data_fim':$scope.data_end, 'funci':$scope.searchFunc})
  //$http.post('assets/php/remessa_rj.php', dados)
  .then(function(resu){
    $scope.thead = false;
    //console.log(resu);
    $scope.remessa = resu.data;
  });
};

$scope.SelectAll = function(){ // select all checkboxes to save in txt file
    //console.log($scope.remessa);
    angular.forEach($scope.remessa, function(item){
      item.selected = event.target.checked;
    });
  };

$scope.salvar = function(){ // employees selected in the box above
    $scope.funciSelected = [];

    // verifica se o vetor $scope.funciSelected foi selecionado alguma vez
    var n = $("input:checked").length - 1; 
    
    if (n === 0) { //console.log("The array is empty!") 
      $scope.funciSelected = 'No employees selected';
      console.log('empty');
    }

    else {   

      angular.forEach($scope.remessa, function(rem){
        if (rem.selected) {
          //console.log(rem.id_funci);
          //$scope.funciSelected.push({'id':rem.id_funci, 'name':rem.name});
          //console.log(rem);
                    
          /* send to file to save in txt */
          // here is the big problem when redirects to save/test.php
          $http.post('salvar/teste.php', rem)
          .then(function(resu){
            console.log(resu);
            window.location.href = 'save/test.php';
          });

          /* end - send to file to save in txt */
        }

      }); // end angular.forEach

  } // end else

  };
```

I need to redirect to this php page and print the values ​​passed by post in angularjs, but it prints null.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
   //$value has the value of each item
   echo($value);
}

//var_Dump($obj);
```

I've tried several ways as friends passed by, I've searched on forums without success.

Comment: If you want to redirect to test.php with data, then submit a form to it, instead of using AJAX

Comment: Your PHP script is expecting JSON - but I rather doubt that `$http.post` actually encodes your data as JSON on its own ...? Much more likely that this is making an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request.

Comment: @CBroe I've already tried with $.ajax, $http.post, $http and without success.

Comment: No one here can tell from that, whether you actually managed to make either of those send the data as JSON, or not. Maybe do a print_r/var_dump of $_POST in your script - if that is _not_ empty, then you were definitively _not_ sending JSON.

Comment: @ADyson Can I submit a form by selecting the select field?

Comment: by "select field" do you mean your "Salvar" button, or something else?

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Are you sure it is related to [tag:null] or [tag:return] after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't know if it's a problem in js or php, but in the js console it works but it doesn't print on the page php returns null.

Comment: @ADyson Example: My table contains several employees, each employee will have a checkbox field to be selected, and those who are selected will go to this php page after clicking a button.

Comment: As I am using angularjs, each selected employee already contains an array with their data that goes to the php page.

Comment: @CBroe I have already added print_r and var_dump, both return data only in the js function, and on the php page itself it displays NULL.

Comment: `and on the php page itself it displays NULL.`...that's because you're sending _two_ separate requests to PHP. The first request is a POST request done by $http.post which contains the `rem` data, and so PHP reads that, and echoes it back to you, and so you can see it in the console when you log the response. The second request is done by `window.location.href` and is a simple GET request which does not contain any of the data. These are two different requests, and each request executes the PHP again, separately. php://input only reads the data which is sent to it during that specific request.

Comment: `Can I submit a form by selecting the select field`...if you put your button and checkboxes within a form, e.g.  `<form action="save/test.php" method="post"> ... </form>` Then the data will be submitted to PHP in a standard POST request (so it redirects you to that pafge, unlike in an AJAX request)  when you click the button. This is very standard behaviour...have you not covered this in HTML training? Using Angular can be great but it feels like maybe you skipped the foundational topic of basic HTML before you started on that.

Comment: @ADyson ``that's because you're sending two separate requests to PHP.`` Got it, I thought it was just redirecting to the desired page.

Comment: The second request redirects to the page, but it doesn't take the data with it. $http.post meanwhile performs a separate, asynchronous background request.

Comment: Is there any way to redirect the data?

Comment: I think I just described one in my last-but-one comment. Use a form.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much.